my app is paused when i call a function that make an http request
there is something wrong with my code, i have a function with an http request to retrieve datas of my users and display it, but each time i call it i have a pause on my app, and this message :Sends an HTTP POST request with the given headers and body to the given URL.
[body] sets the body of the request. It can be a [String], a [List] or a [Map<String, String>]. If it's a String, it's encoded using [encoding] and used as the body of the request. The content-type of the request will default to "text/plain".
If [body] is a List, it's used as a list of bytes for the body of the request.
But i use similar function somewhere else in my code and it works well, i don't know is going on
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class Navbar extends StatefulWidget {
  const Navbar({
    super.key,
    required this.mail,
    required this.password,
  });
  final String mail;
  final String password;

  @override
  State<Navbar> createState() => _NavbarState();
}

class _NavbarState extends State<Navbar> {
  String left = '';
  String amail = "";
  String apseudo = "";

//login() is the function that paused the app anytime i call it
  Future<void> login() async {
    var url = Uri.parse('https://konamicash.com/solde_app');
    var response = await http.post(url, headers: {
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
    }, body: {
      "adresse_mail": 'deenandjigbenou@gmail.com',
    });
    var reponse = jsonDecode(response.body);
    print(reponse);
    setState(() {
      left = reponse['account'];
      apseudo = reponse['pseudo'];
      amail = reponse['mail'];
    });
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    login();
    return Drawer(
        child: ListView(
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      children: [
        UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
          accountName: Text(apseudo),
          accountEmail: Text(amail),
          currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
            child:
                ClipOval(child: Image.asset("assets/images/capture-arene.png")),
          ),
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.redAccent,
            // image: DecorationImage(
            // image: AssetImage('assets/images/capture-arene.png'),
            // fit: BoxFit.cover)
          ),
          //currentAccountPicture: , cicle)
        ),
],
),
);


it seems that the problem comes from setState in the login function because i have this message: DartError: setState() called after dispose(): _NavbarState#b5dde(lifecycle state: defunct, not mounted)  , And when i remove setstate eveything works well

Dont do it bro, use  futureBuilder for login(); or at-least inside initState

yeeeeaaaaah it works with login in initState  thank you, sometimes the answer is so simple that we don't think about it

You should call login function inside initState.
@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    login();
}


use on of the two solutions:
1-Use Future builder
use the future builder widget, which allows you to call a future function and change the content based on the future status or result.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<Map<String, dynamic>>(
      future: login(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          // Show a loading indicator while waiting for the data
          return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          // Show an error message if the request failed
          return Center(
            child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'),
          );
        } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
          //Future finished, Build the UI with the retrieved data 

          return Drawer(
          .....

2- Or use initState, which runs once you build the widget (not recommended for such things like futures.)
@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    login();
}

